# How do I replace / update multiple rows based the possibility that any of the columns in those rows may change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `Customers` which contains a number of columns such as `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DateFileOpened`, `OrderedInLastMonth`, etc... There are more than 20 columns per row, and there are around 500 rows.

Each hour, I have a mechanism that scrapes another source of this data for updated customer records, and puts them into a temporary table, which then need to be copied into my main `Customers` table. However, any or all of the columns in any or all of the new rows could differ to the existing ones in `Customers`.

At present, and to avoid creating nearly-duplicate records, my pretty crappy code does eg a `delete from [Customers] where CoOrigin = 'England'`, before then importing the new ones to take their place. However, I have other queries that need to run at around the same time as this, and often this gets in the way, resulting in those other queries returning 0 data because the customer records that may be returned are missing, thanks to the delete command.

Once again, I'm aware this is terrible coding, but I'm still quite new. I've looked at the update / replace statements but they seem to need to specify which columns in each row need updating, but it could be any of the 20+. I'm aware that this would achieve the task, but it seems like more bad code. I'm also unsure how to reference the temporary table that the new records are imported into, before they are then copied to the main `Customers` table (and the temporary one dropped).

Any help or pointers you can give me would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are the rows being written to updatable by any other process, or are they only updated by the refresh process?

Comment: @Bohemian Only by the refresh process that occurs every hour. Otherwise they aren't touched.

Comment: _resulting in those other queries returning 0 data_ This should be impossible if your update process is within a transaction and your query process is not using any locking "trickery". Show some code. And yes 500 rows is trivial and should be roughly instantaneous for updating.

Comment: It sounds like you are just missing a transactional element to your processing. Show your code for more help.

Comment: There has to be *some way* of correlating which customers are new and which need updating. How would you do that, is there an `ID` column? Sample data and expected output would help immensely, along with you existing code. It looks like you just need a `MERGE` statement

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a microscopic amount of data, so you can use a "big hammer" approach to refresh every customer without impacting other processes.

```
begin;
lock table customer in exclusive mode;
delete from customer;
insert into customer select from temp_customer;
commit;
```

Processes that need access to the customer table will just block while the update completes (a couple of seconds tops) then continue unaffected.