# How to Replace Old Values With New Ones

Tags: sql-server

Apologies, I originally asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614794/how-do-i-replace-update-multiple-rows-based-the-possibility-that-any-of-the-co?noredirect=1#comment123050725_69614794), but I don't think I did a very good job of it. I'm going to try again here, with a little more of the real life scenario...

I have a table called Customers, comprised of 39 fields such as:

```
PersonID, FirstName, LastName, FileOpened, FileClosed, 
FileSuspended, FileSuspendedReason, FileSuspendedChangeDate, RelevantHistory
```

This table is populated through a JSON extract from some 3rd party software, which is then imported into my SQL database. There are customers in multiple locations, but the data extract covers all of them. The extract and import is performed every hour, and I need a better way of ensuring that once the process is complete, my Customers table has the very latest and accurate record for each customer.

Once the first location is processed, this SP is then run for each of the other 6 locations. I'm aware that perhaps the best solution is to import them all in one go, but there is a reason that is not possible which I will not bore you with.

There is no way to predict which of the fields in [Customers] may have changed, and so I need a way that essentially has the effect of removing the old record and replacing it with the new one seamlessly.

Presently, my code for the JSON data import is contained within one stored procedure, and is as follows (I've cropped out the less important aspects. @JSON is linked to the .json file containing data from the extract, and @location_name is passed to the SP when called):

```
SELECT 
    j2.* 
INTO 
    [CustomersDUMP] 
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@JSON) 
    WITH
        (   
            Customers nvarchar(max) '$.customers' as JSON
        ) j1
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J1.Customers)
    WITH
    (       
            CustomerID nvarchar(100) '$.customerID',
            Location nvarchar(30) '$.location',
            FirstName nvarchar(50) '$.firstName',
            LastName nvarchar(75) '$.lastName',
            ClosedReason nvarchar(200) '$.closedReason',
            FileSuspended nvarchar(19) '$.fileSuspended',
            FileSuspendedReason nvarchar(200) '$.fileSuspendedReason',
            RelevantHistory nvarchar(500) '$.relevantHistory'
    ) j2
   WHERE 
        j2.Location = @location_name

DELETE FROM
   [Customers]
WHERE
   Location = @location_name

INSERT INTO [Customers] SELECT * FROM [CustomersDUMP]
DROP TABLE [CustomersDUMP]
```

This is then run consecutively for each location.

I assume this isn't the correct way to do it. Should I create individual SPs for each element and then call them from a master SP, for example? I've tried to read up on transaction management, but as I'm not professionally trained I've had to learn as I go, which can mean sometimes things are a bit difficult to grasp.

There are only around 400 customer records. However, when I then run other queries that involve this table, often the results come back blank (ie select * from [Customers] where location_name = 'XXXXX'), but then if I run the import process again, the query returns the results I expect.

Any help on how to do this properly would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform DML operations of the procedure in the context of a single transaction and make sure that for sessions in which data is selected from the table, at least the read committed transaction isolation level is set.
However, this approach can cause waiting when selecting and updating the table when trying to impose incompatible locks on rows/pages/table.

Possible procedure template:

```
CREATE OR ALTER Procedure dbo.SP
As

SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
-- Other sets if needed.

BEGIN TRY  
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
              
    -- the body of your procedure

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH   
         Print Concat('ErrorNumber: ', ERROR_NUMBER());
         Print Concat('ErrorSeverity: ',ERROR_SEVERITY());
         Print Concat('ErrorState: ',ERROR_STATE());
         Print Concat('ErrorProcedure: ',ERROR_PROCEDURE());
         Print Concat('ErrorLine: ',ERROR_LINE());
         Print Concat('ErrorMessage: ',ERROR_MESSAGE());

    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
    BEGIN   
        --The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    END;  

    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
    BEGIN  
        -- The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
    END;
END CATCH;  
GO
```

Session with a selection request:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

Select * From [Customers] Where location_name = 'XXXXX'
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as this seems quite complicated to my eyes in relation to what the original question was. Would putting my whole SP at present (including the delete and insert into) resolve the issue of seeming to have no entries in [Customers] that match that location_name?

Comment: If I got it right you want to prevent queries from getting uncompleted data (in particular empty data) from [Customers] table during updating the table with up-to-date data via a SP, so performing the delete and insert in scope of single transaction inside the SP don't let the queries to get uncompleted (uncommitted) data. However the single transaction scope it is part of the solution, since queries can read dirty (uncommitted) data through, for example,"NoLock" hint or through read uncommitted transaction isolation level, so you need also to make sure that the queries read committed data.